# How to 'order by' nested in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I use SQL Server 2012 and am trying to sort the results of the following query by the names from the subquery but always get an SQL Execution Error.

What am I doing wrong or missing here ?

**My Query:**

```
SELECT A.EmpID,
       (SELECT B.EmpID, B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName AS TM
        FROM dbo.EmpTable AS B
        WHERE B.SupEmpID = A.EmpID)
FROM  dbo.EmpTable AS A
WHERE  A.NTID = 'someID'
ORDER BY B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName
```

Comment: Presuming there is no comma in either name (unlikely), you can increase the chance that an index is used by not doing the concatenation.  When you call a function on a source column for joining/grouping/ordering (even implicitly, like with concatenation or casting, or even basic math), you make it so that the database can't use an index to fulfil that part of the query, slowing it down (well, optimizers can sometimes work around it, but it's a good first rule to observe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning more than one column in a correlated subquery in the columnlist.
That should give you the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How about using a join instead of a subquery?

```
SELECT A.EmpID,
       B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName AS TM
FROM dbo.EmpTable AS A
  INNER JOIN dbo.EmpTable AS B
    ON B.SupEmpID = A.EmpID
WHERE A.NTID = 'someID'
ORDER BY B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that resolved the issue and works perfect. I will accept as soon as I can. :)